# How to make loop run until condition equals true

Tags: python, loops, repeat, pyautogui

I want the code to keep repeating until it is true

`if pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222: pyautogui.click(1493, 782) else: numpy.repeat()`

i want the program to check if it is the right color and if it is i want it to click it which is the first part, but if it isn't the correct color i want it to repeat the code with 1 sec sleep timer
until the color is right then click on those coordinates

i tried to put `numpy.repeat(1)`  but it said im missing repeats
then i tried putting `numpy.repeats(1)` which game me this error
", line 347, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'repeats'. Did you mean: 'repeat'?

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: If understood correctly, did you try to use a while loop with break?

Comment: If you want a loop that runs until a condition is met, then `while not <condidion>:` is the way to go

Comment: That's not what `numpy.repeat` is for.

Comment: thanks i figured out the problem this is the code i use and it fixed it

while not pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222:
    time.sleep(1)
if pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222:
    pyautogui.click(1493, 782)

is there any way i can make this into a function or something similar as i will likely reuse this

Answer (score 0):

Hi you want to use a while loop as has been identified in the comments.

e.g.

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    if pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222:
        pyautogui.click(1493, 782)  
        break  # Exit the loop once the click is performed
    else:
        time.sleep(1)  # 1 second sleep
```

I noticed you asked how to turn this into a function in the comments. Using your code:

```
def wait_and_click(x, y, color_value):
    """
    Wait until the pixel color at (x, y) matches the specified color_value, then click it.

    Parameters:
    - x, y: Coordinates of the pixel to check.
    - color_value: The desired color value to match.
    """
    while not pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[1] == color_value:
        time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

you can test this by calling

```
wait_and_click(1493, 782, 222)
```

P.S. Note also you don't need the if statement from the code you pasted in the comments. The second check is unnecessary. Your while loop already checks the pixel colour.

Comment: thank you for the help i used this as my function     
while not pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222:
        print("It is not green")
        time.sleep(1)
    if pyautogui.pixel(1493, 782)[1] == 222:
        pyautogui.click(1493, 782)